Regularity of the quotient of a topological group by a closed subgroup
I am trying to solve the following exercise from Chapter 2 (Exercise 7, item (d), page 146) of Munkres's Topology. The statement is as follows:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ that is closed in the topology of $G$; let $p:G\rightarrow G/H$ be the quotient map. Show that $G/H$ satisfies the regularity axiom.

My attempt was as follows. I managed to verify that if $G$ is Hausdorff, then $G$ is regular. More precisely, if $A$ is closed in $G$ and $x\notin A$, then there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of the identity such that $AV$ and $xV$ are open and disjoint neighborhoods of $A$ and $x$, respectively. Then, given $F$ closed in $G/H$ and $xH\notin F$, we obtain by continuity of the quotient map $p:G\rightarrow G/H$ that $p^{-1}(F)$ is closed. I can use the regularity of $G$ to obtain a neighborhood $V$ of the identity such that $p^{-1}(F)V\cap xV=\varnothing$. Then, since $p$ is open, $p(p^{-1}(F)V)$ and $p(xV)$ are open in $G/H$. This produces open neighborhoods of $F$ and $xH$ in $G/H$. Now, I would like to show that these neighborhoods are disjoint, but I don't know how to do that.

Is it possible to continue this argument? If so, how?
If this argument does not work, then how to prove the claim?


Hint: $p^{-1}(F)$ is a union of cosets of $H$. Suggestion: if you're using left cosets, then use $V$ on the left.

@SteveD I tried to use the hint, but I still can't see how to prove that $p(Vp^{-1}(F))$ and $p(Vx)$ are disjoint. I know that there exists a neighborhood $V$ of the identity such that $Vp^{-1}(F)$ and $Vx$ are disjoint, but what would prove the result is confirming that $Vp^{-1}(F)H$ and $VxH$ are disjoint. The problem, it seems to me, is that I don't know how to relate $H$ (and the fact that $H$ is closed) to this argument.

Another hint: $p^{-1}(F)H = p^{-1}(F)$.

(Just as a side note: you use that $H$ is closed to show $G/H$ is $T_1$).

Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. Then every one-point set $\{xH\}\subset G/H$ is closed via the quotient topology (since $xH\subset G$ is closed), and so $G/H$ is $T_1$. Let $F$ be a closed subset of $G/H$, and $xH\in G/H$ a point outside of $F$. We need to find disjoint neighborhoods around $F$ and $xH$.
$p^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $G$, and does not contain $x$. So by the regularity of $G$, there is an open neighborhood $V\subset G$ of the identity, such that
\begin{equation*}
Vp^{-1}(F)\cap Vx=\emptyset
\end{equation*}
Note that using the continuity of multiplication and inversion, we can shrink $V$ so that $V^{-1}=V$ and $V\cdot V\subset V$.
Since $p$ is an open map, we have that $p\left(Vp^{-1}(F)\right)$ and $p(Vx)$ are open neighborhoods of $F$ and $xH$ in $G/H$. We just now need to show them disjoint. But for any subset $C\subset G/H$ and subset $A\subset G$, we have
\begin{equation*}
  p^{-1}p\left(Ap^{-1}(C)\right) = Ap^{-1}(C)
\end{equation*}
This is because $p^{-1}(C)H=p^{-1}(C)$, and so is a union of left cosets of $H$; multiplying on the left by $A$ doesn't change that. So to show our open neighborhoods are disjoint, it suffices to show $Vp^{-1}(F)$ and $VxH$ are disjoint.
If $y\in Vp^{-1}(F)\cap VxH$, then we can write $y=uf$ and $y=vxh$, with $u,v\in V$, $p(f)\in F$, and $h\in H$. Equating these two expressions and isolating $x$, we get
\begin{equation*}
x = v^{-1}ufh^{-1}
\end{equation*}
Now $v^{-1}u\in V$ and $p(fh^{-1})=p(f)\in F$, so this implies $x\in Vp^{-1}(F)$. This is a contradiction with the choice of $V$: no such $y$ exists, and our subsets are disjoint, as desired.
